# Entity Framework 4.1: Override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

```
    public abstract class Animal , IValidatableObject
    {
        public string Id {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (this.Name == "animal")
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid Name From base", new[] { "Name" });
            }
        }
    }




    public class Dog: Animal, IValidatableObject
    {
        public string Owner {get;set;}

  public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        /*
          Here call base validate
         */

        if (this.Name == "dog")
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid Name From dog", new[] { "Name" });
        }
    }     

    }
```

I have a base class `Animal`  which implements `IValidatableObject`, now from `Dog` sub-class's `Validate` method which also implements `IValidatableObject`, I want to call base class's  `Validate` method.

I tried doing (it doesn't call base class's validate)

```
base.Validate(validationContext);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code sample you did not derive your dog class from Animal.
The animal's validation method will only be called if you iterate
through the result set:

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
  public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext      validationContext)
  {
     foreach(var result in base.Validate(validationContext))
     {
     }

     //dog specific validation follows here...
  }
}
```

Only calling base.Validate() without iterating through the returned collection will
not call the base's validation method.
Hope, this helps.

Comment: Actually my code contains this part "public class Dog : Animal" (inherit from Animal). It was just a typo while asking the question, corrected it.

Comment: Did you try calling base.Validate() and iterating through the returned result set? This should solve your problem. The animal's Validate method gets called!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
  public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext      validationContext)
  {
     foreach(var result in base.Validate(validationContext).ToList())
     {
     }

     //dog specific validation follows here...
  }
}
```

You need to call `ToList()` since the base method returns `IEnumerable` type data