# IValidatableObject not working in mvc 4 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, ivalidatableobject

So I have web app that is registering users and business partners.

This is how my models look like

```
public class UserModel : IValidatableObject
{
   //here are some properties and methods that I am using in Validate method        

    public CompanyModel Company { get; set; } //this is user Company

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {       
         if (this.UserWithEmailExists())
             yield return new ValidationResult("Email already exists", new[] { "Email" });

         if (this.UserWithUsernameExists())
             yield return new ValidationResult("Username already exists", new[] { "Username" });
    }
}

public class CompanyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    //again here are some properties that i am using in Validate

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (this.Phone == null && this.Mobile == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("The Phone field is required", new[] { "Phone" });
    }
}

//this is the model passed to the view
public sealed class RegistrationModel : UserModel, IValidatableObject
{
    public new IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (this.Password != this.PasswordValidation)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Ponovite prejšnji vnos", new[] { "PasswordValidation" });
    }
}
```

The problem is: When I submit my form Validate in CompanyModel is called and Validate in RegistrationModel too. But I want also Validate in UserModel to be called...

UPDATE:
I solved the first problem: These are the models after upgrading :)

```
public class UserModel : IValidatableObject
{
   //here are some properties and methods that I am using in Validate method        

    public CompanyModel Company { get; set; } //this is user Company

    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {       
         if (this.UserWithEmailExists())
             yield return new ValidationResult("Email already exists", new[] { "Email" });

         if (this.UserWithUsernameExists())
             yield return new ValidationResult("Username already exists", new[] { "Username" });
    }
}

public class CompanyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    //again here are some properties that i am using in Validate

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (this.Phone == null && this.Mobile == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("The Phone field is required", new[] { "Phone" });
    }
}

//this is the model passed to the view
public sealed class RegistrationModel : UserModel, IValidatableObject
{
    public override new IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //this is needed so that UserModel validation executes
        foreach (var result in base.Validate(validationContext))
        {
            yield return result;
        }

        if (this.Password != this.PasswordValidation)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Ponovite prejšnji vnos", new[] { "PasswordValidation" });
    }
}
```

Now validation works fine. I just do not know why Validate in CompanyModel executes two times??. Any suggestion?

Comment: What model are you passing to your view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you override a method in a base class, the method in that base class is not explicitly called.  You need to do it yourself, so in the `Validate` function in **RegistrationModel**, add a call to the `Validate` function in the base **UserModel** class.

```
base.Validate(validationContext);
```

However, as you use `yield return` in your validators, that makes the `Validate` function an iterator, so it must be iterated through in order for everything to work properly.  As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057419/entity-framework-4-1-override-ienumerablevalidationresult-validate), the full solution is to use this code in your `RegistrationModel.Validate` function:

```
foreach (var result in base.Validate(validationContext))
{
    yield return result;
}
```

Comment: you man...have helped me to find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057419/entity-framework-4-1-override-ienumerablevalidationresult-validate

Comment: Makes sense - you need to iterate through the iterator to make it work.

Comment: I edit my question and added code...two runs in Company Validate?...any idea?

Comment: @TheMentor - Have you reviewed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782484/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-on-nested-objects-not-working-as-expected-validates-c?